# Change Recordtype without Recordtype assigned to profile

Tags: javascript, profile, record-type

**Use Case**
We have RecordType ABC and RecordType DEF. RecordType ABC should be assigned to Profile A but Recordtype DEF should not. Like this, when a user assigned to Profile A creates a record, he/she will not be able to use Recordtype DEF. A button on the page layout will change the RecordType from ABC to DEF.

**Issue**
The custom button needs to change the recordtype from ABC to DEF. Our custom code works, however, the recordtype DEF needs to be assigned to the profile.

The button has some javascript behind it to call a Webservice written in Apex. The Webservice uses a global describe to fetch the recordtype Id. This recorsType is passed back using the webservice to the javascript.

If we check the retrieved Id using the Javascript, we see the correct Id. The record gets updated using the new recordtype but upon saving, the record hasn't changed (when Profile A doesn't have Recordtype DEF assigned).

Any idea how we can achieve this without letting the profile have access to the recordtype?

Comment: Use different credentials on your webservice (one that has access to both the ABC and DEF recordtypes) and then on save also call the webservice to update the current record.

Comment: Thanks TC Sutton! We actually were able to pull it off by calling an Apex class without sharing from the Webservice. But thanks for the hint! Will keep it in mind in case of future problems.